# I found a plant in my garden that I am unable to Identify

Tags: identification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is this plant with long sharp leaves? Is it a weed?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3333/what-is-this-plant-with-long-sharp-leaves-is-it-a-weed)

I found this plant in my garden that I can't identify. I've asked a few people and they don't know either.

It's pretty tall, probably around 1ft, and has long, thin leaves and a darkish, green colouring.

The stem is thin, but sturdy.

Here is a picture:

[image: Unidentified Plant]

Comment: Also related: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/148/how-can-i-get-rid-of-gophers-in-a-non-lethal-way

Comment: Did anyone take into account this could be Nerium oleander? Based on foliage alone it is quite hard to tell the difference, except for internode length compared to the alternative.

Comment: Euphorbia lathyris