# What is this in my garden

Tags: identification, weeds

It is about 4 ft tall and I have no idea what it is can anyone help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: With [tag:identification] questions, it's useful to describe where in the world you found the plant, and the conditions where you found it (sun, shade, rocky hillside, forested riverbank, and so on). If you have more information about the plant, please update your question to add it. Thanks.

Comment: But I think it's [Euphorbia lathyris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphorbia_lathyris); see also http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3333/what-is-this-plant-with-long-sharp-leaves-is-it-a-weed and http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5244/i-found-a-plant-in-my-garden-that-i-am-unable-to-identify

Comment: I agree it is the euphorbia lathyris looking at all the pictures on the web.  Many thanks to all for your help.  :)))

Comment: Spurge, be careful of the milky sap. Some people have allergic reactions to it. Some people call it Mole Plant and hopefully wish the roots will exude this stuff when disturbed. I inherited a garden where somebody planted it. Eventually the compost heap won on eradicating the weed and the mole traps won on eradicating the moles. Nothing like seeing tunnels through a stand of it. Heh, mole repellant, not!

Answer (score 2):

As @NiallC guessed, this is [Caper Spurge, *Euphorbia lathyris*,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphorbia_lathyris) an invasive weed in many areas. I thought it was an annual, but apparently this is a biennial plant. It will grow in zones 5-9. All parts of the plant are poisonous, and handling may cause skin irritations. Care must be taken during removal. It should pull out fairly easily, but you can dig it out if your soil is hard and/or rocky. If the plant has mature seeds, do not add to a composting system unless it is very hot.
[image]

[image]

Comment: LOL. Why is some fool growing a weed in a container in the 2nd photo?

Answer (score -1):

It is Lonicera dioica 'glaucascens' or Wild Honeysuckle. This is actually a rare and endangered in Maine, under concern in Rhode Island. Hummingbirds love this plant. It should have red flowers and red berries, soon. Do you remember the flowers/fruits from last year?

Comment: Sorry, these are not honeysuckle leaves which are oval. Look at the images in this link https://www.google.ca/search?q=lonicera+dioica+'glaucescens'&safe=active&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-SearchBox&prmd=ivns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=EFubU92jFNSlyAS95oHgBw&ved=0CAUQ_AU

Comment: Thanks, Kevin.  Not all honeysuckle have oval leaves, maybe ovalish? Lonicera pileata? I will try to learn how to put pictures up and links.  Had to sooner or later! I'm 90% sure...I'm trying out these keys for ID.  Not easy...is there a good key on the internet that you've found to recommend for us to use? You are really good at the ID stuff! Do you use a key?

Comment: I have the key books but I end up using google images as it's faster. Niall thinks it's a eucalyptus but the seed pods don't look right.  Hm...

Comment: @kevinsky I think it's Euphorbia, not Eucalyptus. On second thoughts, I'm not convinced it's _E. lathyris_ as I've never seen it get bushy like that.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice to know if there was a fragrance? Using photos is my comfort zone but it takes so much time!!!  Trying to narrow it down with a key, but you must be putting in some serious time! (It is a game after all)! And just going through pictures really brings back the different family characteristics...

Comment: It looks like a shrubby vine...liana.  They must have pruned this thing and maybe remember the flowers, fruits.

Comment: Yes it is fragranced.  I moved into this house last year and the wife thought it was a weed and pulled it out.

Comment: Hi Gary! What is fragranced? The flowers, the leaves? Let's talk...

Comment: @Gary It is a weed, pull it out. :)

Comment: I say let it flower before you decide.  It looks healthy and interesting! I'm still looking for an ID on this...

Comment: Back again, NiallC. was right! Forget I said save it, you don't want that around your yard. JMusser was right, pull it out. Sorry, I'll try to do this when I'm not going to be interrupted. Grin.