# How do I get rid of moles and mice humanely?

Tags: lawn, pest-control, rodents

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can I get rid of gophers in a non-lethal way?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/148/how-can-i-get-rid-of-gophers-in-a-non-lethal-way)
>    [How can I get rid of rabbits in my yard](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/140/)
>   [Is there any way to prevent vole lawn destruction during snow cover?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/150/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-vole-lawn-destruction-during-snow-cover)

I have a problem with moles, and possibly mice, burrowing tunnels in my yard and garden and creating piles of dirt. I would like to get rid of them, but I don't like the idea of killing them or using poisonous chemicals. Is there a natural, humane method for getting rid of these rodents from my yard?

Comment: The most *effective* way I know of is a cat. I suppose it's natural, but it's not what you'd describe as "humane"...